# symfony entity : use another entity attribute in a property/to_string method

Tags: php, forms, entity-framework, symfony, addeventlistener

I have an entity (a product) which a user can select thanks to an entity field type.
Selected products become an new entity, userIngredient linked with products by a oneToMany relationship (one product for many userIngredients).

Now, when creating a recipe, the user shall select only products which he has added to its list, so I am using a querybuilder to filter produts and check wether they have a corresponding userIngredient for the user.

This works well but I also want the user to select the product according to its userIngredient name, not its product name.
So I would need to query the oneToMany relationship from the product side=the many side. Here is the issue : in the product entity, I can't call the entity manager.

I would need something like a preset data event not on the parent entity but on the actual products. How to?

```
    $builder
        ->add('product', 'genemu_jqueryselect2_entity', array(
                'label'=>'Ingrédient',
                'multiple' => false,
                'required' => false,
                'class' => 'AppBundle:MarketPlace\Product',
                'property' => 'getUserIngredientName',
                'query_builder'=>$this->queryBuilder,
                'attr'=>array(
                    'data-toggle'=>"tooltip",
                    'data-placement'=>"top",
                    'title'=>"Choisissez votre ingrédient. Seuls les ingrédients faisant partie de votre sélection aparaissent ici.",
                    'class' => 'userIngredient select2'
                )))
```

Here is what I would need to do:

Either in product.php

```
public function getUserIngredientName()
{
    return $this->userIngredients->getName(); //Issue is there is one UserIngredient for every user, I need the one of the current user
}
```

Or in the form

```
$builder->addEventListener(FormEvents::PRE_SET_DATA, function(FormEvent $event){
    $product = $event->getData();
    $form = $event->getForm();
//set the property name here but according to a custom value passed to the type
});
```

Comment: What about creating a QueryBuilder instance that searches for Products based on user ingredients, then pass the user to the form and the query builder?

Comment: yes, I can get the right value to be displayed in the form but I can't see which option it should be applied to? the field option 'property' reflects a method in the entity, the label is for the field and not its choices,... ?

Comment: I guess I'm not understanding what you are trying to do then.  Yes the `property` reflects the entity method.

Comment: I have a product type and I am trying to retrieve a specific entity of a one-to-many relation, on the many side. I'm trying to do product->getUseringredients($user) method on the entity product.

Comment: Do you know which ingredient you are looking for already?

Comment: Not really. More explicitely, I am trying to name the choices of an entity field list, not by the underlying product entity _to_string method but by this entity getuserIngredients() which belong to the current user. I can get this value in the form type cause I can query the database but I don't know how to give a value to the choices of an entity field list in a form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just found out the new feature choice_value from this pull request would allow me to do the trick. I could then pass my product to a function and get the corresponding userIngredient value for the current user.

The pull request :
https://github.com/symfony/symfony/pull/12148

Don't know yet if this is actually merged in the 2.7. Anybody knows?

Answer (score 0):

After going over your comments, I will post this solution and see if it works for you.  You can simply pass the collection you want to the form itself in the constructor.  You can also pass it to the `$options` array if you prefer.

**Controller:**

```
// do whatever you need to grab the entities you want
$em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

$productChoices = $em->getRepository('YourBundle:Product')
    ->getUserIngredients();

// if the form is tied to an entity, pass as the 2nd parameter
$form = $this->createForm(new YourFormType($productChoices));
```

**FormType:**

```
private $productChoices;

public function __construct(array $productChoices)
{
    $this->productChoices = $productChoices;
}

public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder
        ->add('product', 'genemu_jqueryselect2_entity', array(
            'choices' => $this->choices,
            // ...
        ))
    ;
}
```

Comment: Well, could be the solution. For a typical choice field, the array lokks like array('choice.id'=>'choice.displayedText'). Here I would need something like ('product.id'=>'product.userIngredients(User)->getName()'). The issue is that for the entity the choices array has to be an array of entities, doesn't it? So how can I pass both the product id and the useringredient Name ?

Comment: If you have to calculate it, you could create a, variable oxide the class that stores the value you want, then set it before passing to the form. Then just use a getter on that property for your form.